# What is the best way to cross reference two SQL Views in Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm new to SQL queries and need to build a custom report in Microsoft SQL Report Builder 3.0. The data source is a SCCM database. I need help with understanding the best approach to achieve the following:

- We need to cross reference if a computer exist in two Views, if so show that name in the report.
- InputParameter1 = "Please select a View"
- InputParameter2 = "Cross reference with this other View"

If I know the names of the Views beforehand I have a query to get what I need from the SQL server, but I need to create a parameter-based report where you select two Views dynamically and the report cross reference them for you and present which computers exists in both Views.

This is the query I can use for a static result. *v_CM_RES_COLL_CMS0020B* and *v_CM_RES_COLL_CMS000D1* are examples of names of possible Views, until I can solve the parameter issue in Report Builder:

```
SELECT v_GS_SYSTEM.Name0
FROM v_GS_SYSTEM
WHERE Name0 IN
 (SELECT Name from v_CM_RES_COLL_CMS0020B)
AND Name0 IN 
 (SELECT Name from v_CM_RES_COLL_CMS000D1)
```

I don't know how to proceed in how to make the above query into a parameter report in Report Builder. Somehow I need to change v_M_RES_COL_CMS00### to what ever the user inputs to the parameters. Does anyone know how? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you could do is create a Stored Procedure, and pass your view names as parameters of that procedure. Use Dynamic SQL in the procedure to allow you to use the parameters as view names in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've posted this question at a couple of sites and I found exactly what I was looking for below. I would prefer, if possible, to stay out of Stored Procedures for simplicity's sake unless I have to. https://www.windows-noob.com/forums/topic/14538-cross-reference-multiple-collections-in-custom-report/#entry55634